# There seems to be a hole in my engine

Tags: engine, ford

I drive an '07 Ford Crown Victoria Police Interceptor with 146788 miles on the engine. I was looking under my hood today to swap my air filter when I noticed a hole right on the front of the engine below the alternator and near the crank shaft. It almost looks like coolant is in the bottom of it but I cannot tell. Anyone know what may have caused this and how I can fix it?[image]

Comment: Is the hole threaded?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Hard to say without some context. Is that looking down from above or looking up from the bottom of the engine? Is that the water pump pulley in the foreground?

Comment: It's from the top, the visible belt is the serpentine looping over the alternator on top and the crank shaft below. The hole also does not appear to be threaded. I can't fit my finger in the feel if there are any threads either.

Comment: I believe that's the water pump, and the hole is normal.

Comment: I believe Norm is correct. If it starts weeping more, it's time to replace the water pump. This is an indicator of wear on the water pump shaft/bearing. Water pumps generally have plain bearings or bushings. As they wear, the coolant can get to the weep hole. If this were my car, I'd be saving up to have the water pump replaced in the fairly near future. Plus anything else like the belts or timing chain, etc.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a drain hole to drain fluid from bearings etc.

Make sure before you block it...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a plastic tube for A/C condensation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me from the lack of corrosion in a uniform manner around the hole, like a rubber grommet simply cracked and fell out of there. The people that maintain police cars often put access holes like that in to check things without having to tear them down.